# Insert Into Select + Insert Into Values()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_event(mcode, packagetype)
                SELECT fcode, packagetype
                FROM tbl_family_accounts
                WHERE id = '$uID'
            ";
```

The columns `mcode` and `packagetype` is from the table `tbl_family_accounts` and i managed to successfully insert it.

1. How can i improve my query to insert the `event_title` and `event_descrip` from `<form>` or my website.

Answer (score 1):

You can put literals into the `SELECT` list. In mysqli or PDO you would use placeholders for them, and bind them to the POST parameters.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_event(mcode, packagetype, event_title, event_descrip)
    SELECT fcode, packagetype, ?, ?
    FROM tbl_family_accounts
    WHERE id = ?
";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['title'], $_POST['description'], $uID);
$stmt->execute();
```

Replace the `$_POST` indexes with the actual names from your form.

Comment: I dont know about PDO. i wishh but thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I didn't use PDO, that's mysqli.

Comment: Sorry i've just tried it and not working of me. Can you make it simple to undestand please im very new. I dont undestand this part $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['title'], $_POST['description'], $uID);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection